# Computer won´t run after upgrading to13.10

Tags: boot, upgrade

I just upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10, and after the upgrade was done and the computer started rebooting it just didn´t. It freezes after the BIOS screen.
I have tried with "super grub disk" and "boot repair", both beeing burnt in a CD and after switching the boot preference to CDs, but the computer doesn´t read them.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what error shows while booting from CD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a Ubuntu USB and try Ubuntu instead of installing it. from there although this is just a guess, you may be able to hook up an external HDD and access the files on your disk then do a clean install which would honestly save you the time and trouble. Also I was using 13.10 for a couple of months and it crashed all the time and some programs never worked so I switched to the 12.04 LTS which works great. consider that before upgrading your system.

Comment: as you said, in Try mode I could acces to all my data. thanks